# html/php автоотправление POST

Tags: php, html, html5

Есть определенный php скрипт. Переменные в нем задаются методом POST. Возможно ли из другого php или html скрипта автоматом отправить POST со значениями в этот скрипт? Т.Е. открывается php скрипт, в нем обрабатывается полученная информация и он в зависимости от результата автоматом открывает другой php скрипт и передает ему через POST данные. GET не хочу использовать по определенным причинам.

Comment: Не стоит строить кастыли а стоит переписать скрипт.

Comment: html скрипт????

Comment: Файл php, осуществляет регистрацию на сайте. По идее при вводе данных на странице запускается этот скрипт, обрабатывает информацию и в случае успеха перенаправляет на главную страницу, а в случае неудачи перенаправляет обратно на страницу регистрации и через POST передает код ошибки (логин занят, пароли не совпадают, и т.п.).

Comment: используйте языковую конструкцию include не надо придумывать велосипеды

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "Определенный скрипт". Какой? По кофейной гуще гадать?
2. POST запрос можно отправить через **CURL**. Знать бы, куда, как и зачем. Для этого можно спарсить форму на запрошенной странице, и узнать **action**, далее, сформировать запрос и отправить обработчику.
3. Если при определенных условиях Вам нужно обработать другой скрипт, используйте **include** или **require**. Для логической выборки по результатам обработки и последующего исполнения нужного скрипта можно использовать, к примеру, конструкцию **switch()**

Comment: "определенный скрипт"- я знаю его имя и расположение, просто здесь это не имеет значения. А за ответ спасибо. Мне больше подходит CURL.